# cygwin aspell installing new language

Tags: dictionary, cygwin, spell-checking, aspell

have a problem with adding new language to cygwin.

As source for language i tried using ubuntu dictionary files.

It would be interesting if anyone could install any non default languages in cygwin spell checker.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu packages use different directories (`/usr/lib/aspell` vs. `/usr/lib/aspell-0.60` on Cygwin), so this isn't going to work.  Instead, I suggest you build and install these from the source in one of the following ways:

1. Download the latest source tarball for your language from http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/aspell/dict/, unpack the tarball, then run `./configure`, `make`, and `make install`.
2. Use `cygport` to build a package for you, then manually install it.  For example, create an `aspell-lt.cygport` file with the following contents:

   ```
   ASPELL_COMPAT=6
   inherit aspell-dict

   NAME="aspell-lt"
   VERSION=1.2.1.0
   RELEASE=1
   CATEGORY="Text"
   SUMMARY="Aspell Lithuanian dictionaries"
   ```

   Then run `cygport aspell-lt.cygport fetch prep build install package`.  Such a package would then be fit for contribution to the Cygwin distribution.